# Switch Desktops Shortcut / Gesture - windows 10

Tags: desktop, windows-10-upgrade, gestures, windows-10

I know this issue was discusses for preview builds of win10.
Today I installed the final release version of windows 10 and still cant find any shortcut or trackpad gesture to DIRECTLY switch to the next desktop.

Is there any way? Is there the pos. for developer to integrate this feature?
Thanks!

Comment: Touchpad gestures are enabled by drivers.  You will have to wait until the touchpad manufacture releases a driver that adds new functionality.

Comment: But a keyboard-shortcut should be possible?

Comment: Have you confirmed there already isn't a desktop shortcut?  I suspect there is.

Comment: Win+tab doesn't work for you? - http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-tip-switch-between-open-apps-and-desktops

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet discovered all touchpad gestures but you get more if you install latest updates + restart your device(I know that sounds silly)

You can navigate through desktops using Linux Combination key,
CTRL + Windows Key + either left or right arrow key.

Best Wishes.

Comment: Confirming that Ctrl+WIN+arrow will toggle between Desktops.